# How to implement low-latency n-to-n audio chat

Tags: flash, audio, chat

I am investigating on how to implement an n-to-n audio chat (so, lets say 4 people hear each other). This is quite trivial using Flash or Wowza Media Server. The **real** problem is the latency because the 4 people in the chat have to do things as synchronous as possible (for example, something like singing together). Every millisecond matters.

What is your experience with ultra-low-latency audio chats?

- What will be the lowest latency achievable?
- How do you achieve it (which software, protocol, media server, bitrate)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you ever used a telephone, been privy to a teleconference, or watched CNN? Unless you're doing this on a local network, you don't have a prayer.

Comment: I know that a latency below 1sec is probably not possible... but maybe somebody has tried something similar and can share his experiences...

Comment: Well, at least you're realistic :)... when you say "singing," this means to me that the performers are using the sound to determine when they need to sing, and what note to sing, etc. You really need a real-time feel for this type of scenario, so I don't see this being an option with current technology, unless it is a local network, as stated before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lowest latency achievable depends on many factors your code won't have control over, mainly concerning your network.

Now, If I was the one doing this project, I'd see what algorithms and protocols are available for clock synchronization. Once you do this, each host should likely just send time-stamped packets to the server. At the server end, you can combine these packets somehow (maybe a bitwise or over all the bytes for a certain time slot from each machine) and send them out again via multicast.

Trouble is, even your code will have problems... you don't have a way to reliably get those packets to the server in real-time. UDP will drop packets, and you'll have to build a tolerance in for accepting late arrivals or no-shows. TCP is no better in this regard. Sure, the packets are guaranteed to arrive in order, but at what cost in time? Additionally, to compress the sound at each host, then un-compress it at the server, do your combining, and re-compress... all while maintaining the feel of real-time sounds awfully ambitious.

I am by NO MEANs to be considered as being an expert, nor do I have ANY experience doing this type of thing, but it just SOUNDS tough.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion - although only stating the obvious, it seems that you are right - latencies under 1sec seem to be impossible right now. Seems like my client needs another business idea. Thank you!